# Do I Have to JNI Detach an Attached Thread?

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, jvm, java-native-interface

I have some native thread that needs to call into Java.  For that, I need to attach the thread to the VM using `AttachCurrentThread`.  Since this callback will happen quite often, the thread should probably stay attached.  Calling `AttachCurrentThread` multiple times is fine ("Trying to attach a thread that is already attached is a no-op.")

Do I have to call `DetachCurrentThread` before the thread exits, will it happen automatically, or is it not even required?  What happens if I must call detach, but don't?  Would it just "leak," or could this even corrupt the VM state?

I have checked the Java Native Interface specification, but either missed this, or it really is unspecified.

My question applies specifically to Sun JDK 6 on Windows XP.

Answer (score 8):

I think that the confirmation that you want is here: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp1060

> A native thread attached to the VM must call DetachCurrentThread() to detach itself before exiting.

And in the next section, there's the rationale:

> The VM waits until the current thread is the only non-daemon user thread before it actually unloads. User threads include both Java threads and attached native threads.

Comment: Darn, I was looking at the JDK5 JNI spec all the time. The "Detaching from the VM" section is new in the JDK6 docs.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I wish there were more explanation about *why* it must call DetachCurrentThread().  If the native thread is attached as a daemon, then the VM will *not* wait for the attached native thread to finish.